# Push podcasts to Windows Phone 8 without plugging it in?

Tags: 8.0, podcast

I'm wondering if there's a way to push a podcast to my wp8 (or trigger the phone to download it) from my desktop without having to plug it into the desktop?  I'm thinking something similar to the way for the xbox you can log into xbox.com, select a game or demo and trigger it to install on the xbox from your browser.

(Is this something that the "marketplace" allows but only from the US? I've come across a couple of posts that seem to suggest this might be the case, but nothing clear. I'm not in the US so is this the issue?)

Answer (score 4):

The built in podcast app checks on podcasts only when it determines is a good time to. It checks more often when plugged in and on wi-fi. If you want to "pull" a podcast, there are several podcast apps that get good reviews in the store. One that I use to pull a podcast is [bringcast](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=e5abef38-d413-e011-9264-00237de2db9e). It has a free trial.

As an additional note, with the addition of the new podcast app in Windows Phone 8.1, the app is available worldwide with the ability to scan for updates, and download them in the background as well as when you open the app.

Comment: That's where I'm confused. When I go to "Music+Videos" app and into podcasts in there it just says "It's lonely in here. Go to the Store to add some padcasts."   But when I go to the store, there doesn't seem to be any options to add podcasts.  I'm wondering if that's because I activated my account with the region not set to US.

Comment: Podcast support is enabled in a *few* Non-US countries but this list is pretty small.